# is there a safe way to install js libraries for mongodb script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, underscore.js

I want to write some script in js language and interpreted and executed by mongo, as: `mongo script.js`.

A main issue is mongo does not necessarily work as js does. For instance to import the content of a file, I cannot use `import "/file.js"` but I must write `load("/file.js")`.
So, some libraries like [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) are interesting to use in Mongo's scripts. But I don't manage to find how I can do it in a clean and safe way.
Must I download all libraries I am interested in to use it offline ? And, does  it really work to do it this way ?

Comment: The mongodb shell is very limited. You most likely want to run a NodeJS instance, connect to MongoDB and run the code there.

Comment: To learn NodeJS is another time used to learn another big thing. I know that option but the quicker would be to find a solution for mongo itself.

Comment: @JonasWilms tell me. Is it possible to execute a script by nodejs interpreter without need to create a webpage and so on? I mean just launch `nodejs script.js` would do the same as `mongo script.js` ?

Comment: Yes, but while mongo just runs the script with access to mongodb and only mongodb, NodeJS provides a lot of modules that you can use to host servers / work with files etc.

Comment: @JonasWilms well, I tried. The asynchronous properties of Node.js makes my wishes difficult to apply. I want to use `prompt` in order to execute some things considering what is inserted in prompt. Like I can do in Javascript or Python if you see what I mean. I think it is possible to avoid it by inserting action to do in the  prompt's callback function. Embedded functions. But I don't know if this is the right way to do it. I fear to make a terrible mess.

Comment: You could prompt in the terminal. https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html and yes, asynchrony is what JS is all about.